# `annotate` in `ggplot2` reports errors when combined with `facet_grid`

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I want to add two annotations to the ggplot graph.
When the graph doesn't contain a `facet_grid`, such as `p1`, adding such a `annotate` layer works fine, i.e., `q1`. However, when I add a `facet_grid` layer, to the original graph, i.e., `p2`, then adding the same 'annotate' layer, i.e., `q2` results in an error reporting:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): label

Any suggestion? Thanks.

PS, the version of the package ggplot2 I used is 2.2.1.

`p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() 
p2 <- p1 + facet_grid(vs~.)
q1 <- p1 + annotate("text", x = 2:3, y = 20:21, label = c("my label", "label 2"))
q2 <- p2 + annotate("text", x = 2:3, y = 20:21, label = c("my label", "label 2"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the answer I got from the package author, Hadley Wickham:

https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2221

Unfortunately it's very hard to have `annotate()` do this automatically. Instead just do it "by hand" by creating the dataset yourself.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(wt = 2:3, mpg = 20:21, label = c("my label", "label 2"))
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
geom_point() +
geom_text(aes(label = label), data = df) + 
facet_grid(vs ~ .)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that You used for `x= 2:3` and for `y=20:21`. X and Y should be given only one value/argument and not a vector as in Your case. If You change to `x=2` and `y=20`, then the plot appears without any Error:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(vs~.) + annotate("text", x = 2, y = 20, label = c("my label", "label 2"))
```